# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm getting this error while executing this code:

```
declare @adtdays int

SELECT @adtdays = case when 
DATEPART(MONTH,GETDATE()) >
DATEPART(MONTH,CONVERT(DATETIME,Day1)) then 
DATEPART(day,( DATEADD(DAY,-1,
 CAST( CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR) + '
 /1/' +  CAST(DATEPART(year, Day1) AS VARCHAR) as DATE)
 ))) else 0 end 
 FROM ProgProdAlpidi 
WHERE ProductCode  = 'PRODUCT CODE'
```

what im trying to do is if the actual month is greater than the data in field `'Day1'` then substract one day to the actual month, `+ '/1/' +` the year of field `'Day1'`

the desired result should be `'4/1/2017'` convert this to date

then i get this error

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

[this is the data in my table,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pdW6v.png)

The datatype from `Day1` is float

Sorry for not explaining well.. I'm still learning, plus english is not my native language...

Thank you.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  The code makes no sense.

Comment: And what does this have to do with C#? As far as I can see, this is plain SQL...

Comment: It looks like you're attempting to convert "May" to a date. That won't ever work. Explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: You are trying convert a month in a date. it´s impossible to do. Something like: datepart(month, getdate()) == 05. How do you convert 05 in a date?? And as preview comment, it's nothing to do with c#.

Comment: Perhaps you are trying to get the first day of the current month?

Comment: Thanks youre right... i wont tag those language anymore

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what you are trying to achieve in your question but I suspect you want to achieve one of these three things:

```
--If you want the first of the month:
SELECT CONVERT( DATE, DATEADD(d, -(DAY(DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE() - 2))), DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE() - 1)));

--If you want the last of the month:
SELECT CONVERT( DATE, DATEADD(d, -(DAY(GETDATE())), GETDATE()));

--If you want the month in Month format:
SELECT DATENAME(month, GETDATE());
```